# Chrome app in kiosk mode connect to WiFi

Tags: networking, permissions, wifi, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to **connect to WiFi network using API** when the **Chrome OS is in Kiosk mode**?

So when the device is moved to another place with a new SSID, would it be possible to **do the network setup in the kiosk mode**, without the need to switch to the Chrome OS?

Comment: the scenario that you have given currently has no documentation on how to set up network in kiosk mode. An alternative thing you can do is create an alert that you have been disconnected to the network so that you will have to switch back to Chrome OS and manually connect to the network again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no API to configure network settings in a Chrome app, either in kiosk mode or not.  The [chrome.system.network](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_network) API only lets you view the network interfaces.

The only alternative to configuring networks manually by switching to Chrome OS is using the [google admin console](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2634553?hl=en) with a managed chrome device to set network settings.  You would have to add the new WiFi network while the device is still connected to the old network so it can pull down the new settings before moving the device to another place.  The downside is you need to pay for a license to manage the device with Chrome Device Management.